# Im trying to make a code that translates month number to the name of the month

Tags: python, list

This code is what I came up with so far in reading out mm/dd/yyyy as month dd, yyyy what do I need to do to get the translation aspect of the code working?

```
date = input('Please enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ')
month_list = ['January', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'November', 'December']

if date[0] == 0:
      month_num = date[1]
      print(month_list[month_num])
else:
      month_num = (date[0] *10) + date[2]
      print(month_list[month_num])
```

Comment: you want to get from a `mm/dd/yyyy` string the corresponding month name as in `January`, ...?

Comment: btw you're missing February and October

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. One of your problems is you are taking the wrong index position, since index starts at 0. You were also mising February and October from your list. This should work:

```
date = input('Please enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ')
month_list = ['January', "February",'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', "October", 'November', 'December']

if date[0] == '0':
    month_num = int(date[1])
    print(month_list[month_num - 1])
else:
    month_num = (int(date[0]) *10) + int(date[1])
    print(month_list[month_num - 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for that edit, now how do I print out the dd, yyyy

Comment: You can at a statement at the end such as `print(month_list[month_num - 1] + date[2:])`

Comment: While that would work in a way I want it to be printed out as month dd, yyyy